# What happens to my campaign progress if I uninstall StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements, battle.net

I need to repave my machine. I've made progress in the StarCraft 2 Wings of Liberty Campaign that I don't want to lose. I believe the achievements I've unlocked are tied to my battle.net account and will therefore be kept.

What I am unsure of is if my specific campaign progress will need to be backed up before I wipe the hard drive. I don't want to have to replay missions I've already completed or re-buy Armory upgrades.

Do I need to backup any sort of save game information or is it all online with battle.net?

Comment: Given that's it's a Blizzard game, remember to copy your StarCraft II folder and back it up. Makes reinstalling a walk in the park (with potentially all your files intact)

Comment: @Ivo - the last Blizzard game needing that was from 2003, they may have improved since ;)

Comment: Yes, but the only other game to have come out since then is WoW, and everything (but UI mods) has to be stored on a remote server, so "since 2003" isn't a large population.

Comment: @Gnoupi, if I wanted to reinstall WoW, I just copy pasted the WoW folder. I actually found it quite useful to have a portable game!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Campaign progress is stored online. Swapping computers (or reinstalling) shouldn't affect that.

Now that I think about it, I'm not sure if you can save a game in the middle of a mission like you could in SC1, and if so, I'm not sure if that would be saved. But completed missions are completed on other computers.

Update:
I have noticed some things that just don't get saved. Like if you finish a mission, then just purchase armory upgrades, then quit. It doesn't always save the armory upgrades. When the campaign is continued, it picks back up immediately after finishing the previous level. But this happens even on the same computer, and isn't any worse if you reinstall StarCraft II

Blizzard on Starcraft 2 Save Games: [Starcraft 2 Blog](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/601771)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that option. The other machine here doesn't come close to meeting the system minimums. If you could check that would be **AWESOME**. ;-)

Comment: Updated - Verified. Good to go.

Comment: @McKay good to know! Did you find that somewhere? My Google-fu seems to be failing me when searching for StarCraft 2 support questions.

Comment: Discovered by attempt. Yes, this is not Google-fu. This is trying it.

Comment: @McKay you are the man! I waited on hold with Blizzard tech support for 40 minutes and still haven't gotten a support rep. Should have just come here first!

Comment: @McKay on another note if you use the @... distinction when commenting other users will be notified of your reply even if they aren't the answer/question owner: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments/35917#35917

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I remember the @ashteele stuff. I'm glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: Yay cloud computing.

Comment: @tzenes cloud computing is killing us slowly though... Soon we won't be able to buy any software we want.  We'll have to rent it.

Comment: @Mechko This philosophical debate is beyond the purpose of gaming.se take it to meta.

Comment: For the record, you can save your campaign progress in a file too.

Comment: You can even save on the hyperion. Useful if you just purchased upgrades and don't want to do it again when you come back.