# How do I transfer my starcraft 2 profile onto another computer?

Tags: starcraft-2

I recently purchased and installed StarCraft 2. I want to continue the campaign on a friends computer.

How do I transfer my progress onto his computer?

Is there a profile file I can copy to his installation folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to my campaign progress if I uninstall StarCraft 2?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/what-happens-to-my-campaign-progress-if-i-uninstall-starcraft-2)

Comment: The question is different, but the answer is the same. Just the linking of the two is sufficient IMO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe all of your campaign information is stored in the cloud, which means you should just be able to log in on your friend's computer and continue playing.  Battle.net stores all of your information.

Comment: Yep, all you need to do is log into your battle.net account from the other PC.

Comment: You have to move saves, maps and replays manually though.  (I do believe)

Comment: According to what I've seen, your saves are stored in the cloud. I can see maps and replays not being saved though.

Comment: I can see my saves in "My Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts\...\...\Saves"

Comment: I think it depends on whether you want your manual saves or not.  If you just want to finish this mission and then continue on another computer with the next mission, you don't need to worry about it.  If you save in the middle of a mission and want to *continue the mission from that point*, then you will need to copy your save file(s).

Comment: Saves are stored in both places for contingency, I believe.

Answer (score -1):

You will most likely find the files you are looking for in the following area,
[SYSTEM DRIVE]:/USERS/[PC USERNAME]/My Documents/StarCraft II

[system drive] will usually be your C: drive.
[pc username] is the USER name you log in to Windows with.

Copy the StarCraft II folder there to your new main drive, same area.
Start up StarCraft II. All your mod saves, replays etc will be back.
Keep in mind the system drive and user name on the new setup you may have made different.
Should still work fine even if the drive and user name have changed.

Comment: This is far to generic to be of any assistance. Its clear based on the answer you have not played Starcraft II.

Comment: Actually the answer is correct, and takes into account situations where users have installed Windows to drives other than C:. The question was about 'transferring the profile' and this answer covers it.